# How can I solve this complicated equation?

Tags: calculus

So I'm trying to solve this equation, but it doesn't seem to work.

I made $\sigma^2$ using the latter 2 equations and substituted the first $\sigma^2$. It there anything wrong with this idea?

$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{8100}(50000\mu^2-10800\mu+648)
\\\frac{d\sigma}{d\mu}=\frac{1}{81\sigma}(500\mu-54)\\
\\\frac{d\mu}{d\sigma}=\frac{\mu-0.03}{\sigma}
$$

Thanks, Roki

Comment: What is the equation you are trying to solve?

Comment: i think $u$ is the mean value and  $\sigma$ is de standart deviation , the result look like a Normal Distribution

Comment: Do you want to minimize $\sigma^2$ ?

Comment: @callculus that seem reasonable, minimize the cuadratic error

Comment: @juliogodoy Maybe, But a clarification is needed. It´s not clear what the backround of the equation is.

Comment: @callculus yes, you right.

Comment: @juliogodoy I want to find $\mu$ and $\sigma$. I don't think this has something to do with Normal Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, excuse my error.
The next step from your original post will seem to go like this:

$\\\frac{d\mu}{d\sigma}=\frac{\mu-0.03}{\sigma}
\\\frac{d\mu}{\mu - 0.03}=\frac{d\sigma}{\sigma}
\\\int\frac{d\mu}{\mu - 0.03} = \int\frac{d\sigma}{\sigma}
$

Do you know how to solve from here?

Comment: Yes I think so.
$ log[\mu-0.03]=log[\sigma] $. right?

Comment: I tried this,
$ (\mu-0.03)^2 = \frac{1}{8100}(50000\mu^2-10800\mu+648) $
but it didn't work.